# ALTER VIEW gives invalid column name, but SELECT works fine

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2012

I am trying to alter a view and I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PackingList
> Invalid column name 'NetLbs'.

That looks like a self explanatory message, but the problem is the column *does* exist. If I run the select that is part of the view it works perfectly fine.

This is my alter statement.

```
alter view [vw].[PackingList]
as
select b.Id,
   b.NetLbs

from WorkOrderDetails d
join Boxes b on b.Id = d.BoxId
```

If I just execute this part it works fine.

```
select b.Id,
   b.NetLbs

from WorkOrderDetails d
join Boxes b on b.Id = d.BoxId
```

I tried dropping the view and using create, but that failed also.
So then I created the view with this sql.

```
create view [vw].[PackingList] as select null as test
```

And the alter still fails.

However I learned that if I create the view in the `dbo` schema it works. I'm not sure what I should try next.

Comment: I would try putting the schema in front of your tables.  See if that helps.

Comment: Is there an important reason to use the `[vw]` schema for the views? Do you really have so many views that it's important to segregate them?

If there is, then I would suggest qualifying your tables with `[dbo]` within the view definition.

Comment: Also, you joined two tables together and only used data from one.  Is that what you wanted.

Comment: @user3083310 Thank you! That worked perfectly.

Comment: [**Always** specify the schema](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx).

Comment: (Also, the error message says "procedure" because they didn't tokenize that in the error message. Same happens for certain categories of errors in triggers, functions, etc. too. Ignore it.)

Answer (score 1):

[user3083310](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3083310/user3083310) suggested to put the schema in front of my tables. I did that and it works perfectly.

Also see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) from [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) to learn more about why you should do this.